# Video still playing in background when change window

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have HTML5 player in form and use JS to step forward and step back in multi-level form. But, when user click any button (back, reset, etc.) the video is still playing. How to make auto-stop video when fieldset changes?

For example: Do you have a fever -> yes (here is video) -> reset -> video still playing in background.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venntr/1x183c2t/5/)

```
> <video id="video" width="960" height="600" controls="controls" 
> autoplay="autoplay">
>     <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv" />
> </video>

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $('#firstField');
```

Comment: Did you try `$('#video')[0].pause()` ?

Comment: and in addition did you try `.currentTime = 0` for resetting the time?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1x183c2t/6/  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Working example with a snipplet:

```js
$(".pause").click(function(){
  $('#video')[0].pause();
});

$(".play").click(function(){
  $('#video')[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="pause">Pause/Stop</button>
<button class="play">Play</button>

<video id="video" width="960" height="600" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
var vid = $("#video"); 

function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause(); 
}

$(".resetButton").click(function(){
pauseVid();
}
```